# Create MYSQL Table Counting Multiple Categories for Names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, an Events table and a Category table.  The data would look something like this (simplified as I omitted dates):

```
Events:                          
Name   | catid                   
John       35                      
Mary       36                      
Ed         37                      
John       38                      
Tom        39                      
Mary       40

Category:
catid |  category
35      run
35      swim 
36      bike
36      swim
36      run
37      bike 
38      swim
39      swim 
40      run
```

If you think of each row in the events table as another day we have a person and one or more activities that person performed in the day.  Let's say on Sunday John participated in running and swimming the 'catid' in the Events table references the two activities in the Category table.

What I am looking to do is get a table with distinct names and a count of each activity they performed over time. Like this:

```
Name  | run | swim  |bike
Ed                    1
John     1     2
Mary     1     1
Tom            1
```

I know I would probably need some JOIN commands but I am not sure how to setup the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT 
    e.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.Category = 'run' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as run,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.Category = 'swim' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as swim,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.Category = 'bike' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bike
FROM Events as e 
    LEFT JOIN Category as c ON c.catid = e.catid 
GROUP BY e.Name, e.catid
```

**EDIT:** I did not notice that there were 2 Johns in your data set. I have modified the query to fix that. I am also adding a SQL Fiddle to show the changes.

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aa8f/2)

**EDIT2:** Query using `With ROLL UP` with totals row is shown in [**FIDDLE 2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aa8f/28)

Comment: This seems to be the right idea, however, when I execute the statement I get one row with totals for each event summed over all names.  I do not get a list of individual names and totals for each event.

Comment: @user3520372 I have added a fiddle with a modified query. Check it out.

Comment: Sorry- my bad.  You had it right the first time.  I just accidentally used ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY.  Thanks.

Comment: One more question if I may.  I tried using the WITH ROLLUP which gives the column totals as it should and a null value for name.  In trying to replace null in the Name column with "Total" I used the following statement after SELECT: "CASE WHEN GROUPING(e.Name) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE e.Name END e.Name," but I get a syntax error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3520372 I think the syntax you are using is SQL Server syntax, the mySQL syntax query is shown in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aa8f/28).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issues with the structure of your database and data therein.  If you have a table of categories you should not have catid be repeated for different category names.  Might be helpful to get a better handle on the actual structure of the database if you include your code for creating the tables in question.

Comment: This is how the database is structured.  I have no control over that.  The actual database has 10 different categories all linked to names by catid.